# How to access htdocs folder when xampp can't open in mac Big Sur?

Tags: xampp, macos-big-sur

I just found that I couldn't open Xampp after upgrading to Big Sur.
My question is: How do I access htdocs folder?
I'm afraid that it will override the htdocs folder if I install the latest version of Xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check the hide folder named ".bitname" in your profile root folder? If not, try to find the "xampp" folder inside ".bitname/machines" and copy it to another folder to backup current xampp data.

After isntall/reinstall xampp just put the folder back to the same place ".bitname/machines".

Steps:

- Open Finder and make hidden files visible (cmd + shift + .)
- Go to folder /Users/USERNAME/.bitnami/stackman/machines and backup/copy complete xampp folder to a safe place
- Delete everything in folder /Users/USERNAME/.bitnami/stackman
- Download from https://sourceforge.net/projects/xamp...
- Install newest version of XAMPP
- Run XAMPP once for all folders to be created
- Quit XAMPP
- Rename new folder /Users/USERNAME/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp to /Users/USERNAME/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp_original
- Copy saved folder xampp  to /Users/USERNAME/.bitnami/stackman/machines
- Run XAMPP

PS: If you have another MAC maybe is a good idea to test it before using a simulated xampp instalation!